# tex4ht non roman languages inside tabular environment

Tags: tables, luatex, languages, tex4ht, html

I have tables with accented letters and other non-roman scripts, but they do not appear inside the environment `tabular`.

The letters do appear  outside of the tabular environment.

i compile with `make4ht -ul hello.tex`

I use an extension of tex4ht by @michal.h21,

https://github.com/michal-h21/helpers4ht

```
\documentclass[oneside,a4paper, 12pt]{article}

\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{tabulary}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{longtable}
%\usepackage{ragged2e}
%\usepackage{multirow}
%\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
%\usepackage{eqparbox}
%\usepackage{calligra}
%\usepackage{tabu}

 \usepackage{alternative4ht}
  \altusepackage{fontspec}
  \setmainfont{TeX Gyre Termes}
  \newfontfamily\greekfont{Linux Libertine O}
  \newfontfamily\russianfont{Linux Libertine O}
  \newfontfamily\hindifont{Siddhanta}
  \altusepackage{polyglossia}
  \setmainlanguage{french}
  \setotherlanguage{czech}
  \setotherlanguage{greek}
  \setotherlanguage{russian}
  \setotherlanguage{hindi} 




%\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{Q}{>{\global\let\currentrowstyle\relax}}
\newcolumntype{A}{>{\currentrowstyle}}
\newcommand{\rowstyle}[1]{\gdef\currentrowstyle{#1}%
  #1\ignorespaces
}

\begin{document}


Πράγα   \qquad Μολδάβα \qquad ústředních \qquad Запад \\
éè©«»€  \qquad युरोप \qquad cœur \qquad ññā āṇ

\vspace{2cm}



\begin{tabular}{Qc Ac Ac Ac}
\rowstyle{\upshape\mdseries}
Πράγα   & Μολδάβα & ústředních & Запад  \tabularnewline
\hline\rowstyle{\itshape\mdseries}
éè©«»€  & युरोप & cœur & ññā āṇ
\end{tabular}


\newpage



\begin{tabular}{Qc Ac Ac}   \hline
  \rowstyle{\bfseries}
  Heading & Big and &  Bold \\ \hline
  Meek & mild & entry      \\
  Meek & mild & entry      \\
  \rowstyle{\itshape}
  Strange & and & italic   \\
  Meek & mild & entry      \\ \hline
\end{tabular}









%%%\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{ |X|X|X|X| }
%%%  \hline
%%%  label 1 & label 2 & label 3 & label 4 \\
%%%  \hline 
%%%  item 1  & item 2  & item 3  & item 4  \\
%%%  \hline
%%%\end{tabularx}
%%%
%%%\begin{tabular}{| l | p{9cm} |}
%%%\hline
%%%\textbf{Column Name} & \textbf{Column Description} \\ \hline
%%%Test line 1 & Insert text here (line 1)\\ \hline
%%%Test line 2 & Insert text here (line 2)\\ \hline
%%%Test line 3 & Insert text here (line 3) \\ \hline
%%%\end{tabular}


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have found another bug in `helpers4ht`, thanks for testing :). The problem is that character processing is done in `LuaTeX` node processing callbacks. In this case it is `pre_linebreak_filter`, which is called before paragraphs are broke into lines. But it isn't called in certain situations, such as in tabular cells. For supporting of such cases, one needs to call also `hpack_filter`.

I've updated the [helpers4ht](https://github.com/michal-h21/helpers4ht), please install the new version. The correct result:

[image]

Comment: does it work with tabularx, tabulary, longtable and perhaps other packages for tables ?

Comment: I hope so, as long as these environments itself are supported by tex4ht

Comment: q @michal.h21, I have a new problem with this update http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/285890/93524