# Breaking of footnote with pifont in alternative4ht helpers4ht

Tags: footnotes, luatex, tex4ht, html

The last update of  `alternative4ht`, in order to fix the tables in tex4ht [see here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/285795/tex4ht-non-roman-languages-inside-tabular-environment), has a consequence that the redefinition of  `\thefootnote` with pifont is broken.
there are two versions of the redefinition, as explained here.
https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/133268/93524

both versions are broken : there is no longer the adequate symbol printed. it s a some vertical bar which is printed, instead of the numbers.

Note that the  the command `\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\roman{footnote}}` still works, so the problem is  with `pifont+alternative4ht`

This behavior does not appear with the PREVIOUS version of `alternative4ht` dated 31/12/15, the version which has the problems with `tabular`.

note that if the packages  `\usepackage{alternative4ht} and the others` are disabled, then the footnote works.

I compile with `make4ht -ul hello.tex "fn-in"`

I use an extension of tex4ht by @michal.h21,

https://github.com/michal-h21/helpers4ht

```
\documentclass[oneside,a4paper, 12pt]{article}


\usepackage[bottom, hang, perpage]{footmisc}



%%%\usepackage{pifont}\renewcommand\thefootnote{\scriptsize{\ding{\numexpr171+\value{footnote}}}}


%\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\roman{footnote}} 


\usepackage{pifont}
\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\circnum}[1]{%
  \expandafter\@circnum\csname c@#1\endcsname
}
\newcommand*{\@circnum}[1]{%
  \ifnum#1<1 %
    \@ctrerr
  \else
    \ifnum#1>20 %
      \@ctrerr
    \else
      \ding{\numexpr 171+(#1)\relax}%
    \fi
  \fi
}
\makeatother

\renewcommand*{\thefootnote}{\circnum{footnote}}





 \usepackage{alternative4ht}
  \altusepackage{fontspec}
  \setmainfont{TeX Gyre Termes}
%%%  \newfontfamily\greekfont{Linux Libertine O}
%%%  \newfontfamily\russianfont{Linux Libertine O}
%%%  \newfontfamily\hindifont{Siddhanta}
  \altusepackage{polyglossia}
  \setmainlanguage{french}
%%  \setotherlanguage{czech}
%%  \setotherlanguage{greek}
%%  \setotherlanguage{russian}
%%  \setotherlanguage{hindi} 
%\usepackage{zref-perpage}
%\zmakeperpage{footnote}



\begin{document}
\footnote{First}
\dots
\addtocounter{footnote}{18}
\footnote{Last}
% \footnote{Error}
\newpage
\footnote{New page}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

This problem is interesting, you want to use 8-bit font, which doesn't use unicode to output the characters. It works in normal `tex4ht` using transforming characters through `htf` conversion tables, but our `Lua` callback converts each character above ASCII value 128 to unicode char and obeys `htf` conversion process.

As a solution, only explicitly allowed fonts are processed by Lua callback now. Basic fonts such as `cmrm` are enabled by default, the disabled ones are printed to the terminal output:

```
Unsupported font  pzdr
```

fonts which should be processed with the callback can be enabled using

```
\Configure{AllowFont}{font pattern)
```

Please update `helpers4ht` to get these changes.

Modified sample result:

[image]

Comment: but  `alternative4ht` worked before the update for the tables... how must be used  the `\Configure{AllowFont}{font pattern)` , explicitly with with the pifont ? should I also modify the calling of fonts by `fontspec`, like for `\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Termes}` ? Can you put a complete modification of the mwe above ?

Comment: @Koala it didn't worked before, it was just that it didn't process certain boxes, in this case it was for good, in table example it was bad. You don't need to enable `pifont`, you should enable only fonts which can contain unicode. You don't need to modify your document at all, it should work